# Java Scanner getting cleared no matter what, how to prevent that?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm learning Java and I'm making a library. I want to use three methods on the same Scanner, but the scanner is cleared every time.

We're using Jcreator in class and my teacher wasn't able to figure out what was going on either. The only thing that works is

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String typedStuff = kb.nextLine();
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(typedStuff);

    System.out.println(howMany(chopper));
    System.out.println(howManyInts(chopper));
    System.out.println(howManyIntsAndDoubles(chopper));
} 

public static int howMany(Scanner chopper) //
{
    String x = "";
    int y = 0;
    while(chopper.hasNext())
    {
        y++;
        x = chopper.next();
    }
    return y;
}

    public static int howManyInts(Scanner chopper)
        {
            String x = "";
    int y = 0;
    while(chopper.hasNext())
    {
        if (chopper.hasNextInt())
        {
            y++;
        }
        x = chopper.next();
    }
    return y;
}

public static int howManyIntsAndDoubles(Scanner chopper)
{
    String x = "";
    int y = 0;
    while(chopper.hasNext())
    {
        if (chopper.hasNextDouble())
        {
            y++;
        }
        x = chopper.next();
    }
    return y;
}
```

If I input "yes 5.2 2 5.7 6 no" then my output is:
6
0
0

but it should be:
6
2
4

I know that it's clearing the scanner after the first method is run, no matter what order it's in. Even if I convert the Scanner to another data type in the first lines of the method, it still clears the original one. Thanks!

Comment: It's because you are iterating over all the inputs in your first method so scanner has nothing to scan more when it comes to the second function.

Comment: Its weird to do that with the scanner. It would be way easier just to work with the string. And use the stringobject.split(" ") method (it would split up your input string into an an array. Each array entry consists at the split part of the "space symbol". Then you can easily work with the array and for or while loops.

Comment: I can post the right answer if u dont figure it out. hmu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your chopper class does, but I assume it splits the input string on spaces. If that is the case it may be possible that you are indexing to the end of the chopper in the first method howMany() by calling chopper.Next() until it's at the end of the input. The next call to chopper.Next() in another method would be null if you were already pointed at then end of the chopper.

I'd recommend the following:

```
public static String howMany(Scanner chopper){
    String x = "";
    int y = 0;
    int doubleCount=0;
    int intCount =0;
    while(chopper.hasNext()){
        y++;
        if (chopper.hasNextDouble()){
            doubleCount++;
        }
        if(chopper.hasNextInt()){
            intCount++;
        }
        x = chopper.next();
    }
    return x+y+" "+ intCount + " " + doubleCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume this is an academic exercise and you must solve your problem with Scanner's and one method per count.
The problem in your code is that you are using/passing the same scanner for every method, but in the method howMany (is the first called) the code consumes all the tokens of your input. As you can't reset the Scanner to start from the beginning of the input again, a solution can be to declare three Scanner's (again, I'm assuming this is an academic exercise and you must solve it with scanners) and pass each on to your methods.
Tip:you don't need to assign the result of chopper.next() to the variable x if you don't want to use it, you can just call chopper.next().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String typedStuff = kb.nextLine();
    Scanner chopperHowMany = new Scanner(typedStuff);
    Scanner chopperHowManyInts = new Scanner(typedStuff);
    Scanner chopperHowManyDoubles = new Scanner(typedStuff);

    System.out.println(howMany(chopperHowMany));
    System.out.println(howManyInts(chopperHowManyInts));
    System.out.println(howManyIntsAndDoubles(chopperHowManyDoubles.reset()));
}

public static int howMany(Scanner chopper) //
{
    int y = 0;
    while (chopper.hasNext()) {
        y++;
        chopper.next();
    }
    return y;
}

public static int howManyInts(Scanner chopper) {
    int y = 0;
    while (chopper.hasNext()) {
        if (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
            y++;
        }
        chopper.next();
    }
    return y;
}

public static int howManyIntsAndDoubles(Scanner chopper) {
    int y = 0;
    while (chopper.hasNext()) {
        if (chopper.hasNextDouble()) {
            y++;
        }
        chopper.next();
    }
    return y;
}
```